# C++11: Number of Variadic Template Function Parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

How can I get a count of the number of arguments to a variadic template function?

ie:

```
template<typename... T>
void f(const T&... t)
{
    int n = number_of_args(t);

    ...
}
```

What is the best way to implement `number_of_args` in the above?

Comment: `sizeof...(T)`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the "Post Your Answer" form is some inches farther to the bottom of the page. ;)

Comment: @kay-SEisevil _I don't understand why your comment has fewer upvotes than his._

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Just write this:

```
const std::size_t n = sizeof...(T); //you may use `constexpr` instead of `const`
```

Note that `n` is a constant expression (i.e known at compile-time), which means you may use it where constant expression is needed, such as:

```
std::array<int,   n>  a; //array of  n elements
std::array<int, 2*n>  b; //array of (2*n) elements

auto middle = std::get<n/2>(tupleInstance);
```

---

Note that if you want to compute aggregated size of the packed types (as opposed to *number* of types in the pack), then you've to do something like this:

```
template<std::size_t ...>
struct add_all : std::integral_constant< std::size_t,0 > {};
 
template<std::size_t X, std::size_t ... Xs>
struct add_all<X,Xs...> : 
  std::integral_constant< std::size_t, X + add_all<Xs...>::value > {};
```

then do this:

```
constexpr auto size = add_all< sizeof(T)... >::value;
```

In C++17 (and later), computing the sum of size of the types is much simpler using [fold](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) expression:

```
constexpr auto size = (sizeof(T) + ...);
```

Comment: +1 Learned two things; `sizeof...` and `constexpr`. :)

Comment: So this `sizeof...` actually returns the number of arguments and not the combined storage size of all arguments (like `sizeof` on an array would)?

Comment: @panzi: Yes. `sizeof ...(T)` returns *number* of types packed in `T`. If you want to compute aggregated size of the packed types, then you've to do something like this: http://ideone.com/udggBk  I've added this in my answer as well.

Comment: @panzi: the computation in my answer is slightly improved now.

Comment: @Nawaz No that is what I want. I just was suspicious because of the different behavior of `sizeof`. Thanks. :)

Comment: With C++17, to calculate size of individual arg types now we can use fold expressions  `return (0 + ... + sizeof(t));`

Comment: @P0W: Yes. Thanks. I'll add that to my answer once C++17 is out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Args>
struct SomeStruct
{
    static const int size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<typename... T>
void f(const T&... t)
{
    // this is first way to get the number of arguments
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(T);
    std::cout<<size <<std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    f("Raje", 2, 4, "ASH");
    // this is 2nd way to get the number of arguments
    std::cout<<SomeStruct<int, std::string>::size<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```