# Is there a way to get a given number of inputs where the number is given by a template in compile time in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, suppose I make a class like below:

```
template <unsigned int INPUT_SIZE>
class A{
public:
    int operator()(int input, ...){ // get INPUT_SIZE-many inputs
        // return sum;
    }
};
```

I want to get input as many as INPUT_SIZE, not more or less. How can I achieve that?

Also, I am using c++11, but if there is a better way in c++14 or above, I would also like to know.

Comment: With a for loop.

Comment: @tkausl Can you give an example of how that would look?

Comment: Does it need to be [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-friendly? If not, I'd use a `static_assert` inside the body of `operator()`; if so, I'd go with Jans's answer until C++20, at which point I think you can put the `sizeof...` in a `requires` clause.

Comment: See also: [Number of Variadic Template Function Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024304/c11-number-of-variadic-template-function-parameters)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>**[Live demo 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5da67e790a7f727)**</kbd>

```
template <class T, auto> using always_t = T;

template <class T, class Arity>
struct A_impl;

template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
struct A_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    int operator ()(always_t<T, Is>...)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
template <std::size_t N>
struct A : A_impl<int, std::make_index_sequence<N>>
{ };


A<2>{}(1, 2); // fine
A<2>{}(1, 2, 3); // fail
```

and this is a version that allows you to compute the sum of the parameters:

<kbd>**[Live demo 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/268283b7680631d1)**</kbd>

```
template <class T, auto> using always_t = T;

template <class T, class Arity>
struct A_impl;

template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
struct A_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    constexpr int operator ()(std::tuple<always_t<T, Is>...>&& t) {
        auto adder = [](auto... ts) {
            return (0 + ... + ts);
        };
        return std::apply(adder, std::move(t));
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct A : A_impl<int, std::make_index_sequence<N>>{
};

constexpr int sum = A<3>{}({1, 4, 5});
static_assert(sum == 10);
```

The trick is to use a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) with length `N` so that we can use it to expand as `N` times a specific type into the parameter list of `A_impl::operator()`.

A parameter pack can expand into `N` repetition of the pattern that (usually) precede `...`

---

Consider a function like:

```
template<class... T>
void foo(T...);
```

`T...` indicate in simple terms that it can be replaced by successive types into the parameter list of `foo`, one possible expansion could be `foo(int, int, double, char)`, also notice that what preside `...` is an identifier that comes from `class... T`.

---

Returning to the code, we need to generate a parameter pack, we did that through `std::make_index_sequence<N>`, that generate the sequence `0..(N-1)` which is captured by `std::size_t... Is`, then we use this pack to expand the pattern `always_t<T, Is>` that is just an alias to `T=int`, this end up repeating `T=int` as many times as elements `Is` contains.

Note: ellipsis parameter `...` is not the same as parameter pack.

Comment: Okay that's pretty neat

Comment: Is it okay if I ask how this code works? I have never used `...` in practice with templates so it is hard for me to understand.

Comment: @user5876164 I edited the answer with some explanation, hope you understand now.

Comment: `decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})` can be written concisely as `std::make_index_sequence<N>`. Less noise is better.

Comment: By the way, what's the usage of `always_t`? What is `always_t` in `A_impl`?

Comment: `always_t` is just a an alias template, is used to allows for parameter pack `Is` appear on it and be used as a pack pattern.e.g `always_t<int, 0> == int`

Comment: Note that all that examples use C++17, but can be rewritten in C++11 with relative small changes.