# How recursive variadic templates is work?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

With this code:

```cpp
static unsigned count = 0;

template<typename... T>
auto sum(T... args)
{
    ++count;
    return (... + args);
}

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << sum(12, 32, 32, 12, 4, 3, 43, 432) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TIME: " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
$> ./program.out
570
TIME: 1
```

Why is `count` equals to `1`? I expected `count` to be 8. Is `sum` template function called only once?

Comment: Yes, you only make one call to the function; the number of arguments don't matter in counting the number of function calls

Comment: Your sum function would have to call itself for it to be recursive - it doesn't.

Comment: Can you elaborate by what logic you expected it to be 8? Obvious expectation is it to be 1.

Comment: So `return (... + args);` is calculated on compile time without calling function recursively ?

Comment: The expression is transformed into a sequence of addition statements, not recursive calls

Comment: @GhasemRamezani No, the calculation is generally performed at runtime. Just the code for the calculation is generated at compile time according to the actual number of arguments.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I thought `sum` function will be call recursively on rum time.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Why? Body of sum does call sum nowhere.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Recursion means that a function calls itself. You don't do this (nowhere in the body of `sum` is `sum` called), so why do you expect recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `sum` template function call once ?

Yes, it won't be called recursively. Instead, the expression is expanded for [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold#Explanation).

> The instantiation of a *fold expression* expands the expression e as
>   follows:
>
> ...
>   2) Unary left fold *(... op E)* becomes *(((E<sub>1</sub> op
>   E<sub>2</sub>) op ...) op E<sub>N</sub>)*
>   ...
>
> (where *N* is the number of elements in the pack expansion)

You might want to put `++count` into the fold expression, e.g.

```
template<typename... T>
auto sum(T... args)
{
    return (... + (++count, args));
}
```

As [@Xatyrian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575635/how-recursive-variadic-templates-is-work-c17#comment105318245_59575689) pointed, its value is just same as the number of elements in the pack expansion, which could be taken by `sizeof...` too.

Comment: If the goal is to count the number of parameters in the template pack, i would prefer using `sizeof...(T)` as presented in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024304/c11-number-of-variadic-template-function-parameters)

Comment: When i write `(++count, args)`, Compiler(__GCC9__) give me a warning _warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'count'_.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Yes, the evaluation order of multiple `++count` would be unsequenced here; I think it's fine for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to call `sum` multiple times, you could do so recursively:

```
static unsigned count = 0;

template <typename T>
auto sum(T t)
{
    ++count;
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    ++count;
    return t + sum(ts...);
}
```

Comment: No, I am new to `C++ Templates` and  my goal is to know when we use `...` in function body for use remaining arguments, Is recursive function call or not.