# How to get number of function arguments from `decltype(<funtion>)`?

Tags: c++, function, templates, count, arguments

Let's say I have the following function declaration:

```cpp
template<typename signature>
int foo();
```

Given the above-mentioned function, is it possible to define `foo` in such a way, so that it returns the number of function arguments that were passed in the `decltype` template parameter?

So the example usage might look like:

```cpp
int bar(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}

int jar(int a)
{
    return a * a;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << foo<decltype(bar)>() << std::endl; // Desired output: 2
    std::cout << foo<decltype(jar)>() << std::endl; // Desired output: 1
}
```

---

### Edit:

Thanks, everyone for the replies. They do seem to work. However, I forgot to mention one more use case.

Let's say I want to get the number of arguments of the following function:

```cpp
int __stdcall car(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a * b + c;
}
```

The answers so far do not seem to work with this kind of function that uses `__stdcall` convention.

Any idea why and what can be done about it?

Comment: Your edit should be in another question as it has diff. issue than you mentioned in the first post.

Answer (score 5):

For that(i.e. with `decltype`), the given `foo` is not enough. You need something like the followings traits.

```
template<typename> struct funtion_args final {};

template<typename ReType, typename... Args>
struct funtion_args<ReType(Args...)> final
{
   static constexpr std::size_t noArgs = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

Used [`sizeof...`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) operator on *[the variadic template arguments, to get the no of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024304/c11-number-of-variadic-template-function-parameters)*.
And then you can get the argument count directly like

```
std::cout << funtion_args<decltype(bar)>::noArgs << "\n"; // output: 2
```

or pack into the `foo`

```
template<typename signature>
constexpr std::size_t foo() noexcept
{
   return funtion_args<signature>::noArgs;
}
```

**([See Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oYhbr3))**

---

### Better Approach

If you want less typing(i.e. without `decltype`), a more convenient way of getting the arguments count of a free-function, you could do the following

```
template <typename ReType, typename... Args> 
constexpr auto foo(ReType(*)(Args...)) noexcept
{
   return sizeof...(Args);
}
```

Now you could conveniently call the `foo` with other functions as arguments

```
std::cout << foo(bar) << "\n"; // output: 2
```

**([See Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z5cGW9))**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason why I use `decltype` is because I need to use the type of function in foo as well. But that is another matter altogether, hence I did not mention it here.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just have `foo()` call on a suitable trait type.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_helper;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo_helper<T(Args...)> {
    static constexpr std::size_t arg_count = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <typename T>
std::size_t foo() {
    return foo_helper<T>::arg_count;
}
```